# SqlAlchemy or_ with multi-part clauses

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a list of independent clauses that look like:

```
'cls.status = :status_1 AND cls.password_valid = 0'
'cls.status = :status_1 AND cls.reason = :reason_1'
...
```

I'm wanting to add them to the where clause in sqlalchemy

using `query = query.filter(or_(*clauses))` which says to me I should read them (in the where clause) as:

```
WHERE ...
AND ((tbl1.status = :status_2 AND tbl1.password_valid = 0)
     OR (tbl1.status = :status_3 AND tbl1.reason = :reason_1))
```

For some reason when I add multipart clauses to the query, it sees them as single part and I get this instead:

```
WHERE ...
AND (tbl1.status = :status_2 AND tbl1.password_valid = 0 
     OR tbl1.status = :status_3 AND tbl1.reason = :reason_1)
```

Which is NOT equivalent to what I expect.  How do I get it to introduce parens around the multipart clauses that are being OR'd together?  All the examples I find are single clause statements being OR'd so of course they work

Answer (score 0):

Using `or_`, you have to wrap stuff up in a parens separated by commas.

`query.filter(or_(
                  something == 'this', something == 'that'
                   )
               )`

If you want to separate your clauses with parens, you can use the alternate bitwise operator `|`

ex:

`query.filter( (something == 'this') |
                (something == 'that'))`